# How to use the SUMIF function in Excel, or something similar, to count the occurrence of a *word* within a given range?

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I'm trying to use the SUMIF function in Excel, or anything at this point, to sum up the occurrences of a given word within a given range.

For example:

```
  A               B
men              500
groomsmen        500
jolly men        500
```

For the table above I would like to create a SUMIF, or equivalent, function that returns 1000. I've tried

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,"*"&A1&"*",$B$1:$B$3)
```

However that returns 1500 as it matches groomsmen. I've also tried

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,A1,$B$1:$B$3)+SUMIF($A$1:$A$3," "&A1,$B$1:$B$3)+SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,A1&" ",$B$1:$B$3)
```

But that doesn't seem to work as it seems that Excel trims the space character.

Also tried using SUMIFS but that didn't work because the criteria is AND'd together.

I even tried adding regexp support through some addon however the SUMIF function doesn't seem to be that flexible in the criteria it takes so that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: To me, its not clear whether or not you want to match groomsmen or jolly men. However, I just wondered if you've tried the function =SEARCH() or =FIND() depending on you're wanting a solution that also compares capitalization or not. Another function you might want to consider is =MID()
If this problem wont be solved until this evening - I don't have the time right now - I'll try to find a solution to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but here's a formula that returns 1000 for those values:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,A1,$B$1:$B$3)+SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,"* "&A1,$B$1:$B$3)+SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,A1&" *",$B$1:$B$3)
```

Inserting a space before the value will look for an exact match of " men", by adding the asterisk before, will look for anything that ends in " men", the opposite goes for the third part of the formula, looks for anything that starts with "men ".

Comment: Would you also need to allow for `"* "&A1&" *"` to match for the word in the middle of the cell's value?

Comment: As @YowE3K mentioned I also need to catch the case with a space on either side. That said thank you for posting this as I must've missed it somehow?!